# NSXMLParser trouble

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I used an example to get known to `NSXMLParser` but I need to use it not for `appDelegate`, but for other ViewController and this doesn't seem to work:

```
@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {

    [super init];

    viewController = (ViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        viewController.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

        //Initialize the book.
        aBook = [[Book alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        aBook.bookID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aBook.bookID);
    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
        return;

    //There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
    //If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
    // and release the object.
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
        [viewController.books addObject:aBook];

        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

The `viewController.books` doesn't have any objects in it after parsing. Why?

Comment: You are typecasting the AppDelegate towards something you are calling a `ViewController` - looks very fishy.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably get rid of the initXMLParser code. Instead, I would make the view controller an instance variable and set it when you initialize your parser.

```
MyParser *parser = [[MyParser alloc] init]; 
[parser setViewController:self];
```

The other approach would be to make your ViewController a delegate of MyParser. In MyParser.h you could declare some delegate methods:

```
@protocol MyParserDelegate
- (void)foundBooks:(NSMutableArray *)booksArray;
- (void)foundBook:(Book *)aBook; 
@end

@interface MyParser {
     id<MyParserDelegate> delegate; 
     NSMutableArray *bookArray; 
     Book *aBook; 
     ... 
}
@end
```

Then, your view controller would be a delegate:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyParserDelegate> { 

...
}
@end
```

And in ViewController.m you would implement foundBooks: and foundBook:.

Then, in your parser you would call the delegate methods:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
    [self.delegate foundBooks:bookArray]; 
    ...
} 

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
    [self.delegate foundBook:aBook]; 
    ...
}
```